# problem writing pinescript function for tradingview

Tags: function, scope, pine-script

I want to put an indicator in a function so that i can call it multiple times with plot.

What i have gives alot of errors from undeclared variables to not in scope, but i dont know what i'm doing wrong.

```
//@version=4
study(title="WHZ RVI", shorttitle="RVI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")


rvi(il,l,off) =>
    length = input(il, minval=1), src = close
    len = l
    stddev = stdev(src, length)
    upper = ema(change(src) <= 0 ? 0 : stddev, len)
    lower = ema(change(src) > 0 ? 0 : stddev, len)
    rvi = upper / (upper + lower) * 100
    offset = input(off, "Offset", type = input.integer, minval = -500, maxval = 500)


plot(rvi(10,14,0), title="RVI", color=#008000, offset = offset)

h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#C0C0C0)
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#C0C0C0)
hline(50, "Mid Line", color=#ff00ff)

fill(h0, h1, color=#996A15, title="Background")
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` is a script input and must be on the primary scope. Move that out of the function and it should be fine, though it may be tidier and better practice to pass those variables as function arguments.